# Delegate throws error for mongoid document

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I have a problem that I don't understand and can't find a solution to:

```
works:
class Document
  CONSTANT_ARRAY = [0,1,2,3]
  delegate :sum, to: :CONSTANT_ARRAY
end

does not work:
class Document
  include Mongoid::Document
  CONSTANT_ARRAY = [0,1,2,3]
  delegate :sum, to: :CONSTANT_ARRAY
end
```

The latter throws error ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)

To be added, the code was working before the mongoid upgrade, in version ~> 5.0, rails 4, now I have mongoid 7.1.0, rails 5.2.4.1

I'm not sure if it is relevant to add, the code gets called from another class

```
class Items
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :document_fields, class_name: 'Document', cascade_callbacks: true
end

class Another
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :items, class_name: 'Item', cascade_callbacks: true

  def document_fields
    items.flat_map(&:document_fields)
  end

end
```

I have reduced the amount of code in the classes, because I don't see the relevance.

UPDATE: So I've figured out that this works. But is it the right way?

```
  CONSTANT_ARRAY = [0,1,2,3]
  delegate :sum => :CONSTANT_ARRAY
  logger.debug Document.new.sum # prints 6 as it is supposed to
```

Comment: I've used the info from https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/Module/delegate about delegate and the delegate :field => :something is not described there

Comment: As far as I know the ActiveSupport#delegate method expects a `to` parameter from where to delegate the method, `delegate :sum => :CONSTANT_ARRAY` seems strange for me. I replicated this scenario and got no problem using your first example. What Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in Mongoid 7.1.0: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4849